# Is it possible to realize end-to-end SSL connection without using ssl accelerator?

Tags: virtual

[image]

Between a PC and a server I want to realize a ssl connection that terminates at the server.
When there is a BIG-IP between them, do I have to use ssl-accelerator on BIG-IP to make ssl connection?
If not so, all I have to do is that to build a virtual server of 443 port and relate it to the pool member,the server,right?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

no you don’t have to use SSL offload on the BIG IP, you can terminate your SSL on the server if you wish, it might be better to use SSL offload for performance reasons but you don’t have to.